# Как исправить ошибку без Терминала?

Tags: python, linux, tkinter

Вот код:

```
import turtle 

t = turtle.Pen 
times_left=4 
while times_left >= 0: 
     t.forward(50) 
     t.left(90)
```

Вот ошибка:

> Exception has occurred:  `ModuleNotFoundError`
> No module named 'tkinter'

Comment: Это точно весь код? Согласно вашей ошибке, у Вас где-то импортируется модуль "tkinter", но он у Вас либо не установлен/не добавлен, либо путь импорта указан некорректно.

Comment: Убедитесь что в терминале и в ярлыке для запуска (я полагаю, что вы запускаете скрипт через ярлык) используется один и тот-же Питон.

Comment: @Legionary модуль `turtle` использует `tkinter`.